# parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 16

Tags: linux, shell

when I pass the below in shell script I am getting an error `parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 16`

```sh
sgRuleDetail=`echo $sGroupsMyIp | jq --arg sGroupId "$sGroupId" 'select(.sgId | contains($sGroupId))'`
```

Comment: I think the error is coming from `jq` rather than the shell.

Comment: ubuntu@ip-172-31-34-25:~$ jq --version
jq-1.6

Comment: What are the values of the shell variables `sGroupsMyIp` and `sGroupId` that are used in that command?

Comment: Turn on `set -x`, so that you can see better what's going on.